# Xamarin - Project failed to build after adding Google cloud messagin component

Tags: xamarin, google-cloud-messaging

I've Google Cloud Messaging to my project but after adding it, Project stopped building. It gives build output as

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1135,2): error MSB6006: "aapt.exe" exited with code 1.

I searched through net and got info to turn on the "Log verbosity to Diagnostic". It gives the build out in detailed form and after going through the log I came to know that during build below lines gets added to manifest file:

```
provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.google_measurement_service" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider"
```

Issue here is the "${applicationId}", during build it should get replaced with ApplicationId.
This issue can be fixed on Android Studio by doing changes the Gradle file but I'm using Xamarin.

I'm using GCM version 29.0.0.2.

Please let me know the possible workaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The current version of GCM is dependent on Google Measurement service and the error is related to Google Measurement Service.

To solve the issue I downgraded the GCM to the version which is not dependent on Google Measurement service.

you can't do it straight away as Nugget downloads the latest version. So in order to downgrade the version of GCM. Remove the updated version and specify the version of GCM to be downloaded in packages.config file. 
Xamarin Studio will consider the specified version as missing package and automatically download the mentioned package.

In my case I downloaded the 27.0.0 version of GCM.